# why can this code run on windows but not unix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

this code, when running on Windows, can **$watch('Id')** sucessfully, but on Unix it can't.

my html code is:

```
<form name="qryForm">
  <multi-selected class="selected" list="list" allow-all="true" select-value="Id"></multi-selected>
  <button class="btn" ng-disabled="qryForm.$valid" ng-click="getData()"> Search</button>
</form>
```

when i click **multi-selected**(dropdownlist) and choose a key-value, this will change **select-Value** (controlled by my directive.js)

```
$(element).bind('change', function() {
  scope.selectValue = $(element).val();
});
```

at the same time, when selectValue is changed, i try in my controller.js to watch "Id" attr tag (**select-value="Id"**) like this:

```
$scope.$watch('Id', function(value) {
  console.log('$watch.Id==>' + value);
    if (angular.isUndefined(value) || value == null) return;

    if (typeof(value) == 'string') {
      $scope.selectAll = false;
      $scope.qryForm.$setValidity('qryForm.$invalid', false);
    } else {
      $scope.qryForm.$setValidity('qryForm.$invalid', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: are you using the same browser?  if not, are you sure this isn't a browser-related issue instead of an OS-related issue?

Comment: yes, it same browser (use chrome), source is put on UNIX/WINDOWS, provide http request to link

Comment: did you check the browser version if the same?

Comment: yes, same browser/version, just http adress different

Comment: Please show the two different URLs you are using to access the page on the different systems...

Comment: Windows → https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/resource/test/index.html#/

Comment: Unix  →http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/resource/test/index.html#

Comment: different is http/https , maybe is it problem?   windows→https , unix→http

Comment: http://, https://, file:// ?

Comment: can you post your `directive` code?

Comment: did you checked the references to the libraries?

Comment: also check if there are errors in your console

Comment: the libraries or refrences is checked, same :(

Comment: console i also to check, but not have any error

Comment: Using CDN for that? or referred from local directory?

Comment: didn't use CDN to cache , what that means? →referred from local directory

Comment: It means it may not be finding the references properly, open your html code in browser's developer window and check if reference is actually finding the file or not.

Comment: thanks , i will check it! wait a monment :)